# NgbTypeAhead in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, rxjs6

I want to implement [NgbTypeAhead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#focus) with in Angular Material [Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). And, I want TypeAhead to show when the input is onClick() or onFocus(). However, following API document of [NgbTypeAhed::Open on focus](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#focus), it's open TypeAhead on all input in every row.

I think it's because of `click$` and `focus$` observable, but still not find out a way to achieve it.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Section table -->
<div>
  <!-- <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="hover" width="100%"></table> -->
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="data">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> data </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        [ngbTypeahead]="searchData"
        (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
        (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)"
        #instance="ngbTypeahead"
      />
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, data: ''},
  { position: 2, data: ''},
  { position: 3, data: ''},
  { position: 4, data: '' },
  { position: 5, data: ''},
  { position: 6, data: '' },
  { position: 7, data: '' },
  { position: 8, data: '' },
  { position: 9, data: '' },
  { position: 10, data: '' }
];

const states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado',
  'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'District Of Columbia', 'Federated States Of Micronesia', 'Florida', 'Georgia',
  'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine',
  'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana',
  'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Islands', 'Virginia',
  'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './app-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'data'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  @ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;
  focus$ = new Subject<string>();
  click$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  searchData = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));

    return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
      map(term => (term === '' ? states
        : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Better way to solve this might be moving typehead in a separate component https://ng-run.com/edit/vuzgGo0OE24P94X6V1uT